# Having errors with R variables

Tags: android, layout, drawerlayout

I am getting errors on the R variables. The variables are R.id.drawer_layout, R.id.layout, and R.id.main. There is a red squiggly line under the words after id. These are all errors from R. Is there something wrong with my layout? I'm just beginning android programming and this is coming from github.

http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/
^This is where the tutorial and code is from.

```
package com.anshikka.datagushalpha;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    final String[] data ={"one","two","three"};
    final String[] fragments ={
            "com.anshikka.datagushalpha.FragmentOne",
            "com.anshikka.datagushalpha.FragmentTwo",
            "com.anshikka.datagushalpha.FragmentThree"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new    ArrayAdapter(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

     final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
     final ListView navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
     navList.setAdapter(adapter);
     navList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos,long id){
                     drawer.setDrawerListener( new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener(){
                             @Override
                             public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
                                     super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                                     FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                     tx.replace(R.id.main, Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, fragments[pos]));
                                     tx.commit();
                             }
                     });
                     drawer.closeDrawer(navList);
             }
     });
     FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     tx.replace(R.id.main,Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, fragments[0]));
     tx.commit();
}

}
```

Comment: Try to import your R
Add this on the imports
import com.anshikka.R

Answer (score 2):

Import your `R`,

is something like

```
import com.yourproject.R;
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into you imports and if you find "android.R" delete it. Finally, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to import your project's R (using Eclipse as IDE) or just manually add it:

```
import com.anshikka.R
```

After that you should see `com.anshikka.R` on your imports at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose those variables don't exist, since the red line only appears under the words after "id".

If you haven't copied the file `activity_main.xml` provided in the link you mentioned, which defines `"@+id/drawer_layout"`, `"@+id/"main"` and `"@+id/drawer"`, into your project's `res/layout` folder, the corresponding variables weren't generated.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have two main.java classes.  I had this problem a couple of days ago when I imported a project into a current project.  I had two main classes and after I deleted one the R error disappeared.  Also make sure you imported the right R class.  If after you imported the R class you get a redline under .activity_main you imported the wrong R class